# Manually started builds should not start subsequent builds in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

In Jenkins I have jobs A, B and C. Build A is triggered by SCM change, build B is triggered by A, C is triggered by B:

A -> B -> C

I created copy of build B called 'B - Manual', which does not trigger build C. This way I can manually re-run build B without triggering build C.

However, this causes some build duplication. Is there a way to trigger build C only if build B was not triggered manually? This would let me avoid having build 'B - Manual'.

Answer (score 0):

The Multijob plugin might do what you want.
https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Multijob+Plugin

Create a new Multijob "M". Configure "M" to run jobs A, B, and C sequentially.
Trigger "M" on SCM change.

That way, if you just trigger "B" manually, it will not trigger C.